# Why we write "Ferguson Case" instead of "Ferguson's case"

Tags: possessive-pronouns, genitive-construction

Since Ferguson is a city in Missouri, why don't we use saxon genitive to indicate that the riots that took place there "belong" to the city? We could refer to the city with a possesive pronoun:

> "**Its** riots lasted over two weeks"

I am not sure if saxon genitive is used with geogrophical places though.

Comment: Can you add the sentence you are asking about? I don't see the word "case" in your quoted example.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wrote my doubt in the title. Basically I am referring to an historical event and don't understand why everywhere it is mentioned as "Ferguson case/riots" instead of "Ferguson's riots". I wrote the quoted example because I see a relation of possesion between the city and the riots, however it doesn't appear to be written with 's in the media. I will read the rules before posting next time!

Comment: No worries. Makes sense now. I don't quite know the answer, but it's not *incorrect* to say Ferguson's riots. I don't think you could say Ferguson's case, though. Also, when using the "Ferguson case/riot" form, I think you'll find that the word *the* is always used. (Assuming you're not looking at newspaper titles)